# Android: Trouble boot service starting

Tags: android, service, boot

In my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<service
    android:name="com.compagny.myapp.service.HTTPService"
    android:enabled="true" > 
    <!-- To allow start the Android service (for debugging session) -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>    
</service>
```

This application runs on my pcDuinoV2 board. But I have a strange behavior:

- when I start the pcDuino board with no connection with my development laptop (so with external power), my Android service is started but nothing works (I have 2 servers in my app).
- when I start the pcDuino board with a USB connection with my laptop, my Android service is started, and my 2 servers run perfectly.

In the Settings panel, in Android OS (from pcDuino), when I check the running apps, my service hasn't the same size according if I start the pcDuino with USB or external power (4.5MB for the correct behavior; 2.2 for the bad behavior).

Do you understand something guys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have UI or it's only background services?

Comment: It's just a background service. No UI.

Comment: If you are working on Android 3.1+ you need to provide UI or to start your service with flag FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES, otherwise it wont work. It's a security patch from Google. When you install a package by default it's state is STOPPED, till the user will interact with it.

Comment: I added this flag, but no improvement...

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
 @Override  
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {  
  if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) 
  {  
   Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, HTTPService.class);  
   pushIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES); 
   context.startService(pushIntent);  
  }  
 } 
}

Comment: Your application's package state is STOPPED. Your BootCompletedIntentReceiver will not receive any intents till you will change the state. To change the state you need to open UI at least once / start your service with --include-stopped-packages flag from ADB Shell / sign your APK with system certificates and put it into /system/app folder

Comment: You can find more information at http://androidyue.github.io/blog/2014/01/04/package-stop-state-since-android-3-dot-1/

Comment: I signed my application (http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) but now my app doesn't start on my pcDuino board...